# Rails - view text formatted text files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, text

I have a ruby on rails 4 app. I'd like to create my terms_and_conditions file using a text editor and then just have ruby render that file. I think it's easier this way. A file format that allows different font sizes (any font), underline and bold will suffice. What file format would you recommend? Is there a file format that can be easily viewed in rails?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What's the problem with html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good option I use is .md files. Take a look at [this](https://github.com/joliss/markdown-rails). Also there is [strapdown.js](http://strapdownjs.com/) which you don't even need the server to format the markdown file. It's pretty cool.